# Write pandas row `i` and first row to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

**Set-up**

I have a pandas dataframe `df` containing several rows and columns.

Each row resembles an applicant `Pn` and each column the applicants answers `An` to questions `Qn`. E.g.

```
       | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
       ----------------
   P1  | A1 | A2 | A3 |
   P2  | A1 | A2 | A3 |
   P3  | A1 | A2 | A3 |
```

I obtain the answers per applicant in a for loop, iterating over columns for each row,

```
number_of_applications = len(df)
for i in range(0,number_of_applications):
    var1 = df['var1'][i]
    var2 = df['var2'][i]
    var3 = df['var3'][i]
```

this works fine.

---

**Problem**

I want to write an applicant's answers and the respective column names to a csv file. So, for each applicant I want to write,

```
     | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
     ----------------
     | A1 | A2 | A3 |
```

to an applicant specific csv file.

I'd like to do this inside the loop.

---

**Current Code**

```
number_of_applications = len(df)
for i in range(0,number_of_applications):
    path = 'mypath'
    os.chdir(path) 
    df.iloc[i].to_csv('name.csv',encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

which yields a csv file looking like,

```
A1
A2
A3
```

so just the answers, vertically and no column names.

How to get,

```
  | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
  ----------------
  | A1 | A2 | A3 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
path = '/path/to/output/files/{}.csv'

df.groupby(level=0) \
  .apply(lambda x: x.to_csv(path.format(x.name), index=False))
```

The code above will produce one CSV file for each applicant (index value). Files will be named like this:

```
P1.csv
P2.csv
P3.csv
...
```

where `P1`, `P2`, `P3` - applicant names (index values)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does this allow me to iterate over the applicants? I need a csv per applicant.

Comment: This will produce one CSV file per applicant: `P1.csv`, `P2.csv`, `P3.csv` for your sample DF

Comment: @MaxU I could think of some other ways to solve this but you managed it in basically one row. +1